# Lightning Design SVG Icons showing in Lightning Experience in MS IE but not MS Edge

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, browser

I am using the [Lightning Design System Utility SVG Icons](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/icons/) on a Salesforce page. In addition to appearing as expected in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome, I've also done everything necessary (including using svg4everybody) so they appear fine when using:

- Salesforce Classic with IE 11
- Salesforce Lightning Experience with IE
- Salesforce Classic with MS Edge

However, they don't appear fine when using Salesforce Lightning Experience with MS Edge. What is different about Edge with Lightning Experience that they aren't appearing?

Comment: This was supposed to be fixed in Spring '17 but I'm still seeing it as an issue. https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system/issues/247

Comment: Still having this issue with svg4everybody v2.1.9.  Any updates from anyone else experiencing this problem??

Comment: Console error message: `CSP14312: Resource violated directive 'frame-src https: mailto:' in Content-Security-Policy: /resource/1484344071000/SLDS/assetts/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg. Resource will be blocked.`

Comment: Also `SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action` which is the error message that was displayed in IE11 before using @sv-alex's [fix for svg4everybody](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/104401/svg4everybody-for-svg-support-for-lightning-in-ie11)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what is different about MS Edge, but I faced the same problem and managed to solve it by using `svgxuse` instead of `svg4everybody`.

Here are the steps:

1. Go to this GitHub repo: https://github.com/Keyamoon/svgxuse
2. Download the `svgxuse.min.js` file
3. Upload it as static resource to Salesforce
4. Include it in your Visualforce page

Comment: You used svgxuse _instead_ of svg4everybody then? Or in addition to?

Comment: Instead. I haven't used svg4everybody.

Comment: Well I'll be! Thank you, @smukov. It appears to be working in both Edge and IE11, whereas I was only able to support one or the other with svg4everybody. Pretty sure this will take the bounty, but will leave open for a bit longer

Comment: @BrentBow No problem. I'm glad I helped :)

Comment: I spoke too soon; must have tested before the page was pushed.  IE11 is erroring out with "Object doesn't support this property or method" from svgxuse.min.js line 11 col 182 similarly to how it does for svg4everybody :/

Comment: That's interesting... we didn't face the same problem and I just checked it again and couldn't reproduce it. Just to note, we are using the above approach in Visualforce Page with SLDS that is running in Salesforce Classic. I haven't tested in Lightning Experience.

Comment: Ah, I see. Ya, the error only appears in LEX. A workaround for the time being is to use both svg libs, one with a modification just for IE11.